# React - Change size of icon received as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following component:

```
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

const MenuItem = ({data, onClick}) => {
  const menuItemOnClick = () => {
    onClick(data);
  };

  const style = {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    color: "white",
    margin:"auto"
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip title={data.friendlyName} placement="right">
      <ListItemButton onClick={menuItemOnClick}>
        <ListItemIcon sx={style}>
          {data.icon} 
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItemButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

The prop is being passed the following way:

```
myArray.map(entityTypeData => <MenuItem key={entityTypeData.name} data = {entityTypeData} onClick={onClick} />)
```

myArray is defined like this:

```
return [
            {
                name: "X",
                friendlyName: "X",
                icon: <MedicationIcon />,
                entities: []
            },
            {
                name: "Y",
                friendlyName: "Y",
                icon: <BiotechIcon />,
                entities: []
            },
            ...
      ];
```

Further information:
Preferably I want to avoid styling my icon where the array is declared, as this is something for which I want to enforce only when the MenuItem Component is used.

I tried changing the size of the parents, but it doesn't cascade to the child icon.

How can I change the height/width of the icon received as props?

Comment: try to add the CSS on the icon element

Comment: I want this only to happen on this specific component, hence why I cannot use css classes as that will affect all icons. I cannot also style the array itself, as the array is used in other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very similar of what you already did for styling the `<ListItemIcon>` but you need to do it on the Icon it self. For example look at the code bellow:

Create the style object:

```
const iconStyle = {
  fontSize: "40px"
};
```

And in your `myArray` apply the style using the `sx` prop

```
  return [
            {
                name: "X",
                friendlyName: "X",
                icon: <MedicationIcon sx={iconStyle} />,
                entities: []
            },
            {
                name: "Y",
                friendlyName: "Y",
                icon: <BiotechIcon sx={iconStyle} />,
                entities: []
            },
            ...
      ];
```

**UPDATED**

Or based on your comment you can use the existing styling for the `<ListItemIcon>` like this:

```
const style = {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  color: "red",
  margin: "auto",

   "& svg": {
    fontSize: "40px",
   }

};
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-hellman-jpkcf4?file=/demo.tsx) with an example

Comment: Yeah but the component is used from other places not just there. Any ideas how to style the prop component in the component it got received as props?

Comment: Thanks man that was it, didnt know I could style the inner svg from the parent element!.